# Why got "This expression is not callable..." errors from typescript and react js?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm new of typescript. I don't know why got the error.
my data list array:

```
  const {
    data: CUData = { cu: [] as Array<CuType> },
  } = useGetCUQuery();

  let CUDataArray = CUData && CUData.cu? CUData.cu:null;

  const ownCompany = CUDataArray !== null && CUDataArray.filter( 
      company => (company.isOwner && company.userType === 2) 
    );

  const assignedCompany = CUDataArray!== null && CUDataArray.filter( 
    company => (!company.isOwner && company.userType === 3) 
  );
```

Error is:

```
> This expression is not callable.
  Each member of the union type '{ <S extends CuType>(cb: (value: CuType, index: number, array: CuType[]) => value is S, thisArg?: any): S[]; (cb: (value: CuType, index: number, array: CuType[]) => unknown, thisArg?: any): CuType[]; } | { ...; }' has signatures, but none of those signatures are compatible with each other.  TS2349
```

Comment: I just posted an answer but then I looked at the error message again and now I'm not sure about it.  Can you post the part of your code which includes `<S extends CuType>` and `value is S`?  It looks like there's a type guard function somewhere that may be causing trouble.

Answer (score 2):

Typescript isn't sure if the type for the array `CUDataArray` is `CuType[]` or `unknown[]`.  The source of this confusion is coming from the return type of your `useGetCUQuery()` function.  If you edit your post with that function I can look at it.

```
 const {
    data: CUData = { cu: [] as Array<CuType> },
  } = useGetCUQuery();
```

Note that the `as Array<CuType>` here only applies to the empty array which you are using as a default, not to the variable `CUData` if it comes from `data`.

Ultimately you want to fix the `unknown` return type at its source, which is the `useGetCUQuery()` function.  But we can also apply a type to the variable that we get from it. Does this help at all?

```
type CUQueryVal = {
    data?: {
        cu?: Array<CuType>
    }
}

const queried: CUQueryVal = useGetCUQuery();

const { data: CUData = { cu: [] } } = queried; // 'as' is no longer needed
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAwgrgFXNAvFA3gWAFBT1ASwGcB5AdwDsIAnALigCMB7JgGwgEMKBuHfKOERpJI9CnAC2DGr2wBfHDlCRYAVQCKcGiABqHVlDRZc%20ACYdgHAPz1j-fgGM4NqAEFq1DiAA88ERAA%20PnwFeUVsUwgHVg5qaAcmCiJgKABHLWoCCFN6GA0M3X1ZHASklPQoc0tc1QARCw5DDCgnegBtAF0oOW6m9Jos02LsdhS8%20st3TxAm8YaoADIFtQmOADonKCsVho24KDE4VlZh0uSoJkoYJgkwLhm0OcmPLygAQhQ0cWPF5aeOKZeNYAMwIrGANAAFME8AlbvdDAEoJC4XcKCA1sRyFRqL8Wjc0RjBMJkIZPlAAEwAShwVNOiXOHCIRAIAHMqKZrvD0bM6g1ATMPl8jgYljtntMQWCIdRoSZYQSESgkZC3qj7pjSJQaHj1ei1sTqP4yWgAMw07B08IAemtAHIKt4AMpQCAADwhFFMRFgiGQARRDHokIAbvotLk-ZAADSEL3uw5SGix2LTSP%20TpUxFQMOsLSEH1O2PAAAWxHcrJc9yp9CdnW4UBwtsDwdzEd9-ljBHjbsT0moKZeIHTyEz2bgFAA1hRLhRi2WiBWq%20iax3Rx0Gz0AD7NNZ7zd2oA)